# Points of degree $n$ on an elliptic curve

Tags: elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over a number field $k$. It is known that $E(k)$ is a finitely generated abelian group and has a structure of the form $\mathbb{Z}^r \oplus T$, where $T$  is torsion. The integer $r \geq 0$ is called the *rank* of $E$. For a closed point $P \in E(\bar{k})$, we define the *degree* of $P$ to be the smallest degree of the finite extension $K/k$ such that $P$ is $K$-rational. **Take note that we are NOT talking about the *order* of $P$ here.**

Suppose $E$ has rank $r \geq 1$, i.e., it has infinitely many $k$-points. Does it follow that $E$ has infinitely many points of degree $n$, for $n \geq 2$?

I'm thinking about this question because suppose we fix a point $P$ of degree, say, $2$. Consider the automorphisms of $E$ $\varphi_i: P \mapsto Q_i$ for some $Q_i$ of degree $2$ different from $P$ (this is because automorphisms send points to points of similar degree). If $r \geq 1$, are there infinitely many distinct $Q_i$?

Comment: Why restrict your attention to elliptic curves if your question makes no use of the group structure? This is a perfectly sensible question to ask of any algebraic variety, and I suspect the answer is likely yes in that generality but have no idea how to prove it.

Comment: I think this should work, but haven't worked out the details. (Also it doesn't require your condition on infinitely many $k$-points.) An elliptic curve $E$ has at least one morphism $\varphi: E \to \mathbb{P}^1$ of every degree $d \geq 2$: $x$ has degree $2$, $y$ has degree $3$, and we can achieve any $d$ using some monomial $x^i y^j$. Now take a $k$-point $P$ and consider the fiber $\varphi^{-1}(P)$ over $P$. Generically, this fiber should consist of an irreducible Galois orbit of size $d$, each point of which is defined over a degree $d$ extension of $k$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan It's because I wanted to make use of the possibility of $C(k)$ being infinite to see if this fact could carry forward to points of higher degrees. Indeed, there was no group structure involved.

Comment: I think your question is slightly weaker than asking whether, for each $n$, there is an extension $L/k$ of degree $n$ such that $\mathrm{rk}\ E(L) > \mathrm{rk}\ E(M)$ for all intermediate extensions $k\subset M\subsetneq L$. If $n$ is prime, then this is true - see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.0933) - in this case, the only option for $M$ is $k$. It's probably also true if $n$ is composite.

Comment: @Mathmo123 nice paper, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true for $n=2$ for every elliptic curve over $k$ (regardless of rank). Say $E$ is given by the equation $y^2=x^3+ax+b$. It is a theorem of Cassels that we can find a prime $p$ so that $k$ embeds into $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and $|a|_p = |b|_p =1$, provided $a$ and $b$ are nonzero. If either one happens to be zero the argument will go through all the same. Now let $c=1+ap^2+bp^3$. Since $v_p(c/p)=-1$, $c/p$ is not a square in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and hence not in $k$ either. Let $L=\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{c/p})$, which is totally ramified over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ with index 2. Thus the valuation $w$ on $L$ satisfies $w(z)=2v_p(z)$ for all $z\in\mathbb{Q}_p$. The point $P=(\frac{1}{p}, \frac{\sqrt{c/p}}{p})$ satisfies our defining equation and is defined over $k(\sqrt{c/p})$ (resp. $L$) but not over k (resp. $\mathbb{Q}_p$). Now, every point $P'=(x', y')$ on $E$ defined over $L$ can be written in the form $(x',y')=(\zeta\pi^{-2n},\eta\pi^{-3n})$ where $\zeta$ and $\eta$ are integral in $L$, $\pi=\sqrt{p/c}$ is a uniformizer for $L$, and $n=\text{max}\{0, -\frac{1}{2}w(x')\}=\text{max}\{0, -\frac{1}{3}w(y')\}$. In this way we obtain a number $n(P')$ for every $P'\in E(L)$. Note that if $P'$ is defined over $\mathbb{Q}_p$, then $n(P')$ is even. Finally, it is a theorem of Lutz that this function $n$ has the following property: if $n(P')\geq 1$, then $n(mP')=n(P')+2v_p(m)$ for every $m\neq 0$. Our point $P=(\frac{1}{p}, \frac{\sqrt{c/p}}{p})$ satisfies $n(P)=1$ and therefore $n(mP)=1+2v_p(m)$ is odd and therefore not defined over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ for $m\neq 0$ and a fortiori it is not defined over $k$ either. In this way we have produced infinitely many points of $E$ which are defined over a quadratic extension of $k$, but not over $k$ itself.

Much of this argument comes from Frey and Jarden's paper "Approximation theory and the rank of abelian varieties over large algebraic fields." I imagine a closer inspection of their paper would yield a positive result to your question for every $n\geq 2$, but I couldn't say for certain at the moment.

Comment: This is interesting, I'll have a look at the paper you mentioned, thank you. Do you know if for every $2$ distinct points $P_1,P_2 \in E(\bar{k})$ of degree $2$, coming from two (not necessarily distinct) quadratic extensions of $k$, we can find an automorphism of $E$ sending $P_1$ to $P_2$? For $k$ an algebraically closed field this would follow from a corollary of Hartshorne Chapter IV, but in this case I'm not sure.

Comment: Are you sure you want an automorphism and not, say, an isogeny? Elliptic curves have very few automorphisms. In fact if $k$ is algebraically closed, then $E$ has at most 6 automorphisms so your claim can't be correct considering we just found infinitely many degree 2 points.

Comment: I'm confused, Lemma 4.2 of Hartshorne Chapter IV clearly states that for any two points $P,Q$ of an elliptic curve $E$ we can find an automorphism of $E$ of order 2 such that it sends $P$ to $Q$. Where did I misunderstand?

Comment: When Hartshorne says "automoprhism" here he means an automorphism of the variety underlying $E$, i.e. this map may not respect the group structure. Typically when one refers to "automorphisms of an elliptic curve" they mean "automorphisms of the variety that are also group homomorphisms" (which is what I meant when I said "automorphism" in my previous comment). It is a fact that every map $E\rightarrow E$ can be written as group homomorphism followed by a translation.

Comment: Since the "automorphism" then refers to a composition of a group homomorphism followed by a translation, it would seem to me that we can simply pick two points $P,Q$, with not necessarily the same degree, and find a map sending $P$ to $Q$ then? After all, since translation does not preserve the group structure, I suppose the "automorphism" does not need to preserve the residue field?

Comment: Hartshorne is always working over algebraically closed fields, so this "swapping" automorphism is a priori only defined over $\bar{k}$.